# localStorage is saving my data but after refresh is reseting and empty it

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, local

I have a problem and I need you to help me understand it. I am using ReactJS and I am building a simple CRUD Todo App. I Want to store my todos in local storage.
The data is saved there and I can see it but after the refresh it is emptying my local storage.

What am I doing wrong?
Something that I notice is that from the first time when I open the app (first rendering), local storage is creating the storage space without adding a todo.

Could I have missed something in my code that makes it reset it or empty it when the page is rendered?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {
  faCheck,
  faPen,
  faPlus,
  faTrashCan,
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import "./App.css";
import { faCircleCheck } from "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons";

function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState("");

  const [todoEditing, setTodoEditing] = useState(null);
  const [editingText, setEditingText] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const json = window.localStorage.getItem("todos");
    const loadedTodos = JSON.parse(json);
    if (loadedTodos) {
      setTodos(loadedTodos);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const json = JSON.stringify(todos);
    window.localStorage.setItem("todos", json);
  }, [todos]);

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newTodo = {
      id: new Date().getTime(),
      text: todo,
      completed: false,
    };

    setTodos([...todos].concat(newTodo));
    setTodo("");
  }

  function deleteTodo(id) {
    const updatedTodos = [...todos].filter((todo) => todo.id !== id);
    setTodos(updatedTodos);
  }

  function toggleComplete(id) {
    let updatedTodos = [...todos].map((todo) => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        todo.completed = !todo.completed;
      }
      return todo;
    });
    setTodos(updatedTodos);
  }

  function submitEdits(id) {
    const updatedTodos = [...todos].map((todo) => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        todo.text = editingText;
      }
      return todo;
    });
    setTodos(updatedTodos);
    setTodoEditing(null);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="app-container">
        <div className="todo-header">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="todo-input-text"
              placeholder="write a todo..."
              onChange={(e) => {
                setTodo(e.target.value);
              }}
              value={todo}
            />
            <button>
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} />
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div className="todo-body">
          {todos.map((todo) => {
            return (
              <div className="todo-wrapper" key={todo.id}>
                {todo.id === todoEditing ? (
                  <input
                    className="edited-todo"
                    type="text"
                    onChange={(e) => setEditingText(e.target.value)}
                  />
                ) : (
                  <p className={todo.completed ? "completed" : "uncompleted"}>
                    {todo.text}
                  </p>
                )}
                <div className="todo-buttons-wrapper">
                  <button onClick={() => toggleComplete(todo.id)}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircleCheck} />
                  </button>
                  {todo.id === todoEditing ? (
                    <button onClick={() => submitEdits(todo.id)}>
                      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheck} />
                    </button>
                  ) : (
                    <button onClick={() => setTodoEditing(todo.id)}>
                      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPen} />
                    </button>
                  )}
                  <button
                    onClick={() => {
                      deleteTodo(todo.id);
                    }}
                  >
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashCan} />
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: from the first render is allocating the space]

[image: after I add a todo ass you can see is saving it to my local storage but after the refresh is empty just like in the first image]

Comment: I tried the code here, and it works fine, there is an undesirable sideffect since your second effect wipes the storage on first render, but the first effect has already retrieved the value so as soon as it sets it back, your second effect is reexecuted and localStorage re-updated:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gkpfsd?file=src%2FApp.js . I added a timeout so if you check the localStorage tab you see that for 2000ms it gets set to an empty array. That's before the first effect saves the previously retrieved value at state, and second effect re-executed.

Comment: that's really helpful, thank you man for this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be loading todos from localStorage on the Component mount if they are available in localStorage like this,

```
const loadedTodos = localStorage.getItem("todos")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"))
  : []; // new

const [todos, setTodos] = useState(loadedTodos); // updated
```

And then you don't have to mutate the state using setTodos(loadedTodos) in the `useEffect`.

Just remove this useEffect , from the code:

```
// that useEffect should be removed
useEffect(() => {
    const json = window.localStorage.getItem("todos");
    const loadedTodos = JSON.parse(json);
    if (loadedTodos) {
      setTodos(loadedTodos);
    }
  }, []);
```

You can check this in the working [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-lederberg-g9yty3?file=/src/App.js) as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think your second useEffect is causing it to reset.

Move that the useEffect logic to a separate function.

And instead of calling `setTodos`, call that function, update the storage, and then call `setTodos` from that function.

Comment: that was the problem, now I get it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you call the setTodos function with a callback function and spread operator like this it should work:

```
useEffect(() => {
const json = window.localStorage.getItem("todos");
const loadedTodos = JSON.parse(json);
if (loadedTodos) {
// set local storage like this
  setTodos( prevTodos => [...prevTodos, ...loadedTodos] ); 
}}, []);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).