# My local storage is not saving after page refresh

Tags: reactjs

I am new at this and I am creating a note app, but the new notes that I add are not being saved on the Local Storage. It does appear on the Application but when the page is refreshed, it disappears. Where am I getting it wrong?

````
        const savedNotes = JSON.parse(
            localStorage.getItem('notes-app-data')
        );

        if (savedNotes) {
            setNotes(savedNotes);
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(
            'notes-app-data',
            JSON.stringify(notes)
        );
    }, [notes]);```
````

Answer (score 4):

I think the your using React in strict mode.

Try to remove StrictMode in index.js

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode> // remove this tag
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helped, thank you so much! Any idea why it behaves that way?

Comment: @ReaganS94 StrictMode in react renders the code twice(on development but not production). First run sets localstorage to data given, then the second run overrides it so now data is blank

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
const [savedNotes] = useState(localStorage.getItem('notes-app-data'))
const [notes, setNotes] = useState(
        savedNotes ? JSON.parse(savedNotes) : []
)

useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("notes-app-data", JSON.stringify(notes))
}, [notes]);
```

Comment: Tried and also continues not saving on my local storage.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the variable `notes` is defined using useState with an initial value of `null`.

This would mean that your useEffect hook is being called on page refresh, and then you are setting your `notes-app-data` item to null, effectively deleting it.

You can fix this by ensuring notes is not null before using setItem, for example

```
useEffect(() => {
 if(!!notes) {        
  localStorage.setItem(
   'notes-app-data',
    JSON.stringify(notes)
  );
 } 
}, [notes]);
```

Comment: Did this work Marcela?

Comment: No, it did not. It still not saving on my local storage.

Answer (score 0):

This answer helped me, https://stackoverflow.com/a/71961318/16282690

Delete this code:

```
    const savedNotes = JSON.parse(
        localStorage.getItem('notes-app-data')
    );

    if (savedNotes) {
        setNotes(savedNotes);
    }
```

and try this but declare it out of function scope

```
const savedNotes = localStorage.getItem('notes-app- 
data')
? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes-app- 
data')) : [];
```

then update useState:

```
const [notes, setNotes] = useState(savedNotes)
```